# Passing objects in actions vs attributes

Tags: reactjs, redux

In the examples I saw in the redux repo, it seems like the action objects always contain the attributes of the state we are creating/editing rather than passing in the object directly. For example

```
/* In the action creator */
export function addTodo(text) {
  return { type: types.ADD_TODO, text }
}

/* In the reducer */
....
case ADD_TODO:
  return [
    {
      id: state.reduce((maxId, todo) => Math.max(todo.id, maxId), -1) + 1,
      completed: false,
      text: action.text
    }, 
    ...state
  ]
```

Is there any particular advantage to doing it this way instead of, say, passing a 'todo' object directly in the action and adding any missing elements in the reducer?

I am working on an app where the object being passed in has many attributes and I find that I have to repeat extracting these attributes from the action in every reducer function. Isn't it easier to have, say in the previous example, action.todo to be set to the relevant object and have the reducer only add in whatever attributes are missing (such as the id)?

Is this some kind of convention/pattern that I am failing to grasp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally I think your actions should be as simple as possible, conveying only the minimum amount of information they need to. But you can certainly change the structure of your actions to a format more convenient to process. A common pattern is to point to all the data with a `payload` key. e.g.

```
    /* In the action creator */
    export function addTodo(text, date, priority) {
      return {
        type: types.ADD_TODO,
        payload: {
          text,
          date,
          priority
        }
      };
    }

    /* In the reducer */
    case ADD_TODO:
      return [
        Object.assign({}, action.payload, {
          id: newId()
        }, 
        ...state
      ];
```

Your payload forms the basis of your todo object. Instead of extracting several attributes, you're only extracting one.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I would suggest that this sort of design decision is "up to you," just as it was for the designer of the code you are looking at.  There are no *categorical* advantages to one approach vs. any other, in nearly every case.

If you find, in your case, that you are "repeating yourself," and especially if you notice that "extraneous" bits appear to be showing-up in "every" reducer function, then I suggest that you should follow your instincts.  The strategy that you see being used in the code that you are using as a model, might very well **not** be appropriate for *your* case, and you should feel entirely empowered to make that *engineering* decision.

To put it another way: IMHO, from an *engineering* point of view, I certainly do not like to see *anything* "repeated in every case," unless it truly *belongs* *to* "every case," because otherwise it **couples** the many (otherwise "unrelated") cases together!

**Ponder:** *"what if* such-and-such change needed to be made in the future? Would the change be "appropriately isolated," or would it "ripple" across the entire source-code Universe like an infernal bowl of Jell-O, and "for no good reason?" From a *software engineering* point-of-view, that would "suck ... for no good reason."  Therefore, it would be prudent to avoid it.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. I am very new to redux/react (started like 2 weeks back). So I wasn't sure if there was anything "canonical" to doing things this way even though in retrospect it seems rather simple. 

For example, initially I didn't understand why most examples I saw were using the "thunk" middleware. Later I came to understand why it was done that way. 

Since I am only starting out with this project, I can change such decisions easily.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old post but still worth the extra answer. I was too coming from the world of OO programming and I stumbled upon this as well:

You'd be typically advised to pass a json to a redux action rather than the object that would be born of it since it allows to to have much more comfortable debugging and testing capabilities. For both, you'd need to serialize your "data" and if this data is an object/instance etc it cannot be fully serialized. This is opposed to mere attributes or configuration of the object passed along.
It a different perception of how to get things done, with really nice benefits.

Note the careful phrasing - I cannot say that you should not pass an instance, nor that its better to not pass an instance. But this is the common sense, preferred way, today.

A few more words on this here:
https://redux.js.org/faq/design-decisions#why-doesnt-redux-support-using-classes-for-actions-and-reducers